# javascript : testing object property length

Tags: javascript

I have some objects with properties. I wanted to test to see if they had characters in them so I initially wrote this:

```
if (MyObject.Prop1.length > 0) {....}
```

However, sometimes the object may not have a certain property so I was getting the error "cannot get length".

I changed it by writing this:

```
if (MyObject.Prop1 && MyObject.Prop1.length > 0) {....}
```

I'm using the chrome inspector and when I run the code, I don't get the error anymore. Is this going to work in every browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `Prop1` will always be a string? Because now, if it contains the Number `0`, your condition will be `false`. And numbers don't have a length property also.

Comment: @baz: well if it contains 0 then the length won't be larger than zero and thus the call probably shouldn't be made anyway

Comment: @Martin All depends on the logic of the application :).

Comment: What happens when we have this: MyObject.Prop1 = 4; ? I only have strings ... for now, but's still WIP.

Comment: @baz: nevermind i am tired and need sleep, sorry for my useless and very wrong comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative:

```
if ('Prop1' in MyObject && MyObject.Prop1.length > 0) { ... )
```

Or, to be even more careful:

```
if (MyObject.hasOwnProperty('Prop1') && MyObject.Prop1.length > 0) { ... }
```

Of course that might be the wrong thing to do, depending on the nature of "MyObject".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work quite fine, although you can save yourself the `> 0` and just do

```
if (MyObject.Prop1 && MyObject.Prop1.length) {....}
```

since anything other than zero will evaluate to true.

Comment: What if one day Prop1 becomes an integer? How should I change this?

Comment: @frenchie Pointy's and Jordan's answer gives some clues. Maybe ask a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Since `undefined`, `0`, and `""` are all "falsy" in JavaScript, this is equivalent:

```
if(MyObject.Prop1) {
  // ...
}
```

Rick Waldron's ["Idiomatic JavaScript"](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js#cond) is a good reference for simplifying conditional statements without sacrificing correctness. You can test its use yourself:

```
function testProp(val) {
  if(val) {
    return val.length;
  }

  return "nope!";
}

var myObj = { stringProp   : "foo",
              emptyStrProp : "",
              // undefinedProp is not defined
              zeroProp     : 0,
              twelveProp   : 12,
              otherObjProp : document.createElement('div'),
              arrayProp    : [ 'a', 'b' ]
            };

console.log( testProp( myObj.stringProp    ) ); // => 3
console.log( testProp( myObj.emptyStrProp  ) ); // => "nope!"
console.log( testProp( myObj.undefinedProp ) ); // => "nope!"

// of course if you're expecting values other than strings and undefined
// you'll have to account for them

console.log( testProp( myObj.zeroProp      ) ); // => "nope!"
console.log( testProp( myObj.twelveProp    ) ); // => undefined
console.log( testProp( myObj.otherObjProp  ) ); // => undefined
console.log( testProp( myObj.arrayProp     ) ); // => 2
```

Comment: To clarify, `0` is "falsy" and all other numbers are "truthy," so if `prop === 0` then `if(prop)` will evaluate it as false, and if `prop == 1` or `5` or `-10` or `3.333` then `if(prop)` will come up true. If you evaluate `prop.length` where `prop` is equal to anything without a `length` property (including numbers), though, you will get `undefined`, which is falsy. I hope that's helpful.