# javascript testing .length and .length > 0

Tags: javascript

I have some text in an object's property. I'm testing to see if the object's property has text in it to display; if it doesn't then I display "-" instead of just a blank. It doesn't seem like there's a difference between:

```
if (MyObject.SomeText && MyObject.SomeText.length) { ... }

if (MyObject.SomeText && MyObject.SomeText.length > 0) { ... }
```

Are there any edge cases where one syntax would be preferable to the other?

Comment: As long as the values of `.length` are in the range `[0,∞)`, it should be fine.

Comment: why do you ask a very similar question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423754/javascript-testing-object-property-length

Comment: another question by him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424275/javascript-testing-length with length again
Are you obsessed by length?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

they give same result. Btw, if its "text", then `if (MyObject.SomeText)` is enough

Comment: What could do wrong? I'm first testing to see if there's text in the property before calling .length on it. How should I rewrite my test?

Comment: If there's text, then there MUST have .length so do NOT need to check again. To be clear: `''` (empty string) is consider false just as null, undefined, 0 and false as well

Comment: my pleasure. You must be new to JavaScript for this newbie question. since you have such a huge reputations. In JavaScript, every var is very very flex, basically no type, what value you give it, it becomes the type. So `if('')` the `''` becomes bool and value is false. I don't like JavaScript, too many mistakes after you have a chunk of code :(

Comment: Actually, I'm building a single page webapp that relies a lot on javascript: it's about 13K of javascript so far. But I'm a business guy who's just starting out in tech: 2 years ago I didn't know what classes, json, or SQL were about. So I started reading 5,000 pages of computer books to learn programming and start a company. Take a look at this: http://answers.onstartups.com/users/15155/frenchie The reason I'm asking about length is that I want to be sure I'm doing it right. If tech people could learn sales, finance and marketing, more startups would be born; the reverse is also true.

Answer (score 9):

> Are there any edge cases where one syntax would be preferable to the other?

Only edge cases where `MyObject.SomeText` or `MyObject.SomeText.length` is not what you expect it to be – for instance:

```
MyObject = {
    SomeText = {
        length: -42
        // or length: true
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

No, they are equivalent, if the length equals to 0 then it is valued as `false`.

(This is possible because JS is not strongly typed, in strongly typed languages length would not be castable as boolean).

Answer (score 3):

It's the same:

```
Boolean(MyObject.SomeText.length)
```

- returns `true` if `MyObject.SomeText.length` != 0
- returns `false` if `MyObject.SomeText.length` == 0

and

```
Boolean(MyObject.SomeText.length>0)
```

- returns `true` if `MyObject.SomeText.length` > 0
- returns `false` if `MyObject.SomeText.length` <= 0

But `MyObject.SomeText.length` can only be `0` or a positive integrer. So

- If `MyObject.SomeText.length` == 0,

  - `Boolean(MyObject.SomeText.length)` returns **`false`** because `MyObject.SomeText.length` == 0
  - `Boolean(MyObject.SomeText.length>0)` returns **`false`** because `MyObject.SomeText.length`<=0
- If `MyObject.SomeText.length` > 0,

  - `Boolean(MyObject.SomeText.length)` returns **`true`** because `MyObject.SomeText.length` != 0
  - `Boolean(MyObject.SomeText.length>0)` returns **`true`** because `MyObject.SomeText.length` > 0

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, a number is only considered "falsey" when it is 0. Any other value is "truthy". Therefore, the statements `number != 0` (comparison, not identity) and `!number` are exactly equivalent.

The only way your two statements would differ is if `length` was something other than a positive number.

Comment: no, number != 0 is NOT equivalent to !number - it's the boolean opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer from the viewpoint of a someone who cares about reading code and human thought.

Yes, they're effectively the same, so it comes down to style.

- `MyObject.SomeText.length > 0` asks **explicitly** "are there characters in this string"?
- `MyObject.SomeText.length` asks "does this string have a length property"? It relies on extra knowledge that JavaScript **implicitly** does the same check as the previous.

I prefer the concept of [don't make me think](https://sensible.com/dont-make-me-think/).

No-one, in the future, skimming over `MyObject.SomeText.length > 0`, even a junior developer will ever have to question, what does the if check do? are there any edge cases?